# Xamarin forms - Create complex custom control (create multiple traffic signs)

Tags: user-interface, xamarin.forms, custom-controls, custom-renderer

I have the following screen in an Android project:

[image]

How can I create controls like this in Xamarin forms? (I really don't want to implement it native).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Frame and set the **Padding** and **CornerRadius** .

For example

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

    <Frame BackgroundColor="Red" CornerRadius="10" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="50" Padding="5">


        <Frame BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="8" WidthRequest="90" HeightRequest="40" Padding="5" >

            <Frame BackgroundColor="Red" CornerRadius="8" WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="30" Padding="0">

                <Label Text="11111" TextColor="White"  FontSize="20" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

            </Frame>

        </Frame>

    </Frame>

</StackLayout>
```

[image]

You could put the above code in a custom view and binding the color and text in code behind.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To be sure: I need to place this code in a custom control and setup the binding via the codebehind of the custom control. Then use this custom control in my contentpage and do the binding? Am i understanding you correctly?

Comment: Yes , I set the color and text as static value just for demo .You could set them as you want .

Comment: And also, at run-time I want to decide which custom control to take, what can I use for that? A valueconverter? Or?

Comment: "Of course , it's up to you", But what control should be made and changed to the run-time-picked control? A boxview? A label? I mean, I need to return the new custom control and set it to a control that is already defined right? This would be my last question.

Comment: You could use control template .

Comment: I really can't figure it out, this is the last problem I am running against.. at this point I just created a contenttype object in the xaml file. It has a converter, the converter returns a custom control based on a specific value. But the problem is that I cannot bind with the binding properties because it is a contenttype rather than the specific custom control...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078403/xamarin-forms-create-show-custom-control-based-on-a-condition